# Why i add responisve to tinymce v4 but not working?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

Example:

```
.mce-content-body p{
    margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    line-height:1;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .mce-content-body p{
    font-size:116%;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
 .mce-content-body p{
    font-size:120%;
 }
}
...
```

But tag p not receive font-size. I try add !important still not working.

Comment: Have you ensured that your styles are not being overridden by other styles with higher specificity?

Comment: yeah, i checked, it not receive responsive.

Comment: You probably need `@media screen and (min-width:  ...)` instead of `@media (min-width: ...)`.

Comment: ty for help, but still not working :(